# Which exception is throw by URLFetchService for timeouts?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, exception, urlfetch

The Google App Engine UrlFetchService has a setDeadline FetchOption which is suppose to raise an exception when tripped.

> The app can specify the maximum amount of time to wait when it makes the call. If the maximum wait time is exceeded, the call raises an exception.

Which Exception?

If it is an IOException, how should I discriminate between a deadline timeout and other causes?

Answer (score 1):

A google.appengine.api.urlfetch.DownloadError will be raised.

Comment: Perhaps this error class is not defined on the java platform? DownloadError class is not found in the appengine-api-1.0-sdk.1.3.7.jar file.  http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/package-tree.html

Comment: Hey Nick J, can you please tell me if the DownloadError class is public or private and what class extends ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the list of exceptions below that are defined/thrown by the urlfetch service.

Not sure if ApiDeadlineExceededException is the one.

```
    com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.UnknownException
    com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.ResponseTooLargeException
    com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.RequestTooLargeException
    com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.OverQuotaException
    com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.FeatureNotEnabledException
    com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.CapabilityDisabledException
    com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.CancelledException
    com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.ApiDeadlineExceededException
    com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.ArgumentException
    com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.CallNotFoundException
    com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.RPCFailedException
    com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.ApplicationException
    com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.ApiProxyException
```